# Concatenating Excel and CSV files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I've been asked to compile data files into one Excel spreadsheet using Python, but they are all either Excel files or CSV's. I'm trying to use the following code:

```py
import glob, os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

par_csv = set(glob.glob("*Light*")) +  - set(glob.glob("*all*")) - set(glob.glob("*Untitled"))
par

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in par:
    print(file)
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read(file)])
```

Is there a way I can use the pd.concat function to read the files in more than one format (si both xlsx and csv), instead of one or the other?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are doing in your code there, but in general you can read both datasets using `pd.read_csv()` and `pd.read_xlsx()` and then `pd.concat()` the first to the second. In the end you can save them together in one sheet. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you!